# How to travese through an adjacency matrix?

Tags: java, adjacency-matrix

Say I have the following adjacency matrix produced

```
     A B C D E F G H I    
   A 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   B 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   C 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   D 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
   E 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
   F 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
   G 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
   H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   I 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Whats the best way to traverse through to confirm that I can go from G to B?
since

```
  [G][D] = true
  [A][D] = true
  [A][B] = true
```

G-->D-->A-->B

I am aware of BFS/DFS but stumped as to what I can do with this matrix so that I can implement BFS/DFS for it.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to see if you can reach some node use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: yes, you have a graph. It is only represented as a adjacency matrix.

Comment: @eNetik, yes you do have that graph.  The vertices are represented by either matrix index and edges between vertices are represented by the values of the matrix.  For example, in your matrix above, D's neighbors are A, C, and G.  This is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use any old graph search, for example:

- [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
- [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the adjacency matrix by itself, you'll get a matrix that contains all paths with a length of 2 and so on.

Your matrix raised to the power of n will show you the number of paths of length n between all the nodes.

Of course if you only need the distance between two nodes, you don't have to do the full matrix multiplication.